# Missing site information in the distribution management of the project spring-swagger-wordnik-client

Tags: maven, https, ssl-certificate

I am trying to create a Maven repository for a project of mine.

The relevant lines in my project's `pom.xml` file are:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>edu.mills.cs180a</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-swagger-wordnik-client</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>spring-swagger-wordnik-client</name>
    <version>0.0.2A-SNAPSHOT</version>
...
  <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <id>CS180A site</id>
      <url>file:///C:/Users/ellen/Dropbox/Apps/site44/www.spertus.com/cs180a</url>
    </repository>
  </distributionManagement>
...
  <build> 
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.1</version>
      </plugin>
    ...
    </plugins>
</project>
```

I get this error when I try to deploy the site:

```
$ mvn site:deploy
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] -----------< edu.mills.cs180a:spring-swagger-wordnik-client >-----------
[INFO] Building spring-swagger-wordnik-client 0.0.2A-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-site-plugin:3.7.1:deploy (default-cli) @ spring-swagger-wordnik-client ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.055 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-11-11T15:24:38-08:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.7.1:deploy (default-cli) on project spring-swagger-wordnik-client: Missing site information in the distribution management of the project spring-swagger-wordnik-client (edu.mills.cs180a:spring-swagger-wordnik-client:0.0.2A-SNAPSHOT) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

I don't understand why I get this error:

```
 Missing site information in the distribution management of the project spring-swagger-wordnik-client
```

What else should be in distribution management besides this?

```
  <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <id>CS180A site</id>
      <url>file:///C:/Users/ellen/Dropbox/Apps/site44/www.spertus.com/cs180a</url>
    </repository>
  </distributionManagement>
```

Comment: It seems you cannot resolve a dependency. In your pom.xml (or in any transitive dependency), there's a dependecy like this: <groupId>edu.mills.cs180a.wordui:wordui</groupId><artifactId>wordui</artifactId><version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>. Maven try to download this dependency with url: http://www.spertus.com/cs180a/edu/mills/cs180a/spring-swagger-wordnik-client/0.0.2-SNAPSHOT/spring-swagger-wordnik-client-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar But this resource doesn't exists. Is it correct your dependency? NB: This download is with http not https.

Comment: @lquitadamo Thanks for commenting on this. I realized the problem was with creating the site and rewrote my question.

Comment: In tag distributionManagement you have to define <site> tag as explained here: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/usage.html. Can you try to set site element?

Comment: @lquitadamo Thank you! That did it. It confused me that I need to have both a `<site>` tag and `<repository>` tag with the same contents. Would you like to make an answer I can accept? I'd be happy to give you bounty too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your configuration, you need to add  element inside distributionManagement  as explained here: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/usage.html.

Comment: Thank you. I found I needed to add identical <site> and <repository> tags.